# #dig wrapper method to accept a dynamic number of variables

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a method that accepts an unknown number of arguments and performs a Hash#dig on them.

```
def unknown_dig(hash, *args)
  # do some magic?
  hash.dig(non_array_args)
end

#example usage
unknown_dig(hash, 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for `hash.dig(*args)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash#dig (defined in Ruby 2.3) already does this:

```
hash = { a: { b: 1 } }
hash.dig(:a, :b) == hash.dig(*[:a, :b])
```

If you want to it more functional style (where you pass the hash as an argument instead of calling the method on it), it's easy:

```
def hash_dig(hash, *args)
  hash.dig(*args)
end
```

Comment: where did you find the documentation for that? I was looking at this http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

Comment: The keyword here is the splash operator `*` not with `dig` itself.

Comment: @userFriendly: the very link you posted shows that dig takes one or more keys: `dig(key, …)`

Comment: I don't think they want functional-style, we should not encourage that in Ruby.

Comment: @akuhn i don't understand why you don't encourage functional practices in ruby. I wasn't trying to say it's an alternative to OOP, I was meaning that the syntax OP used is akin to the functional style (i've been learning Erlang).

Answer (score 5):

[Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) was bestowed upon us in Ruby v2.3. To support earlier Ruby versions you can use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`). This is how we did it when I was a kid.

```
def dig_it(h,*keys)
  keys.reduce(h) { |obj,k| obj && obj[k] }
end

h = { a: { b: 1 } }

dig_it(h, :a, :b)
  #=> 1 
dig_it(h, :a)
  #=> {:b=>1} 
dig_it(h, :a, :c)
  #=> nil 
dig_it(h, :c, :b)
  #=> nil
```

If `obj` is a hash, as it is initially (`h`), when `k` is passed to the block `obj[k] #=> nil` if `obj` does not have a key `k` (or if `obj` has a key `k` whose value if `nil`), in  which case `obj && obj[k] #=> obj && nil #=> nil`. The block calculation will therefore be `obj && obj[k] #=> nil && obj[k] #=> nil` for each of the remaining elements of `keys` that are passed to the block. (`nil[k]` would raise an exception but it is never executed.) If the hash `obj` has a key `k` with value `false`, the same outcome will result except `false` (rather than `nil`) will be returned.